# If I disable third-party cookies, is there any point installing anti-tracking extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies

I have already disabled third-party cookies. Is there any further advantage to be gained by installing [Ghostery](https://www.ghostery.com/en-GB/), [Adversity](http://adversity.uk.to/), [DoNotTrackMe](http://www.abine.com/index.html) etc, or do extensions like these simply allow fine-tuning?

Comment: The DoNotTrackMe extension is basically dead, there are basically 0 playes that will honor it, when they recieve it.  IE is the only browser that sends it by default.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you load a page with a Facebook like button, Facebook knows you are there, even without setting a cookie. Ghostery stops those buttons being loaded, thereby preventing Google, Facebook, Doubleclick from tracking you.

Answer (score 1):

Many advertizers now user [browser fingerprinting](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) to identify you, in addition to cookies. They may also use other tracking techniques like flash cookies.

Ghostery, Adblock (with the anti-social list), and also NoScript will prevent you from loading files from these advertizers/trackers, which makes it very hard for them to track you using other means.